# How to fix buggy Intel Broadwell video driver

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, video, intel-graphics, gpu-driver

I'm running Ubuntu 14 on a Librem 13 laptop, and everything works perfectly except for video.

I usually use the laptop with an external HDMI monitor, and when connected, Gnome will flicker and windows will appear superimposed on each other and be unusable until I minimize and re-maximize them. Also, every time I disconnect the monitor, and then suspend and resume the laptop, Gnome crashes or the login prompt freezes.

I'm using the default video setup and open source driver that Ubuntu sets when you install it. Is there any way I can debug this problem or optimize the video driver?

lspci shows my gpu is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Intel driver is in a state of junk when it comes to Broadwell/Linux, and Intel knows it. It is unclear what their priorities are. Ubuntu is only 1% of their market.
bugs are here: https://bugs.freedesktop.org
search for like DRM Intel. They use kernel version.

- GNOME is in a sad state, too. Run the oldest you can stand, maybe even KDE/X.
- Stay away from non-stable staging code. Downgrading packages is not easy.
- GNOME resume sometimes takes over a minute. It may be waiting for network or some.

The broke gdm, too. For some reason they run multiple copies. If GNOME crashes, gdm is sometimes unable to restart less series of kill -9. Finally they disabled virtual terminals, so you have to ssh in from another machine.

The name of the game is to find some workable procedure and suffer forward. If you can't figure out resume, switch to KDE.